# Using Structures to Store and Accumulate Information About Users in a Chat Log

Tags: c, struct

The point of my program is to read in a .txt file line by line and parse the text to accumulate information for each user who enters text. I have already coded opening the file, reading a line and gathering some information from it. I am using a structure to store the information for each user. So far, I have kept track of the total number of characters for a user and the total number of words, but I am failing at keeping track of the number of characters just in the words (no white space, punctuation, etc.) and at keeping track of the number of messages each user has entered. At the end of my code, I have 4 printf statements to check the values of 1) total characters, 2) number of characters just in the words, 3) number of words typed by the user, and 4) number of messages sent by the user. The problem is with 2 and 4, as the output is spitting out huge numbers, like 32,600 for 2 and in the millions for 4. I'm hoping someone can let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance! Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINELENGTH 200

struct userName
{
int totNumChars;
int numWords;
int numMessages;
int numCharsWords;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
FILE* textFile;
char buffer[MAX_LINELENGTH];
char strName[40];
int numCharsTot;
int numWordsInMesg; 
int userCharsWordTot;



textFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(textFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
    return 0;
}
while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINELENGTH, textFile))
{


    char *token1;
    char *token2;
    numWordsInMesg = 0;
    userCharsWordTot = 0;

    token1 = strtok(buffer, "<>");      //Gets time stamp
    //printf("First token: %s\n", token1);
    token1 = strtok(NULL, "<>");        //Gets username
    //printf("Second token: %s\n", token1);
    strcpy(strName, token1);            //Stores the username into an  array


    token1 = strtok(NULL, "<>");        //Gets message typed by username
    //printf("The message: %s\n", token1);

    numCharsTot = strlen(token1);       //Gets total number of    characters   of line


    token2 = strtok(token1, " ,.!:;#*()[]@$/\"\\&\t\n\r<>");
    while(token2 != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token2);
        numWordsInMesg++;
        userCharsWordTot += strlen(token2);

        token2 = strtok(NULL," ,.!:;#*()[]@$/\"\\&\t\n\r<>");

    }


    struct userName strName;

    strName.numMessages += 1;
    strName.numCharsWords += userCharsWordTot;   
    strName.totNumChars += numCharsTot;
    strName.numWords += numWordsInMesg;
    printf("Number of Characters: %d\n", strName.totNumChars);
    printf("Number of Characters, just words: %d\n", strName.numCharsWords);
    printf("Number of Words by user: %d\n", strName.numWords);
    printf("Number of messages: %d\n", strName.numMessages);    


    }

    fclose(textFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  If you are using C++, please switch to `std::string` and `std::vector` as you will have fewer problems.

Comment: Looks like it's a C language, so you should remove the "C++" tag.'

Comment: Please use your own debugger, as I'm having issues with mine so I can't debug your program for you.

Comment: you are creating a new struct in each iteration of the loop with `struct userName strName` and it is never initialized, so `strName.numMessages +=1;` and the like are incrementing undefined values. You will need to create the user structs dynamically in a data structure.